# JavaFX Scene CSS Doesnt Work

Tags: css, javafx

mainClass.java:

```
public class mainClass extends Application{
    Scene scene;
    Group group;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stg) throws Exception{
        stg.setTitle("Hi");
        stg.setWidth(600); stg.setHeight(250);
        group = new Group();
        scene = new Scene(group, 600, 250);
           scene.getStylesheets().add("mainClass.css");
        stg.setScene(scene);
        stg.centerOnScreen();
        stg.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

mainClass.css

```
.mainClass-scene{
    -fx-background-image: url("background.jpeg");
    -fx-background-repeat: stretch;   
    -fx-background-size: 600 250;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, black, 30, 0.5, 0, 0); 
}
```

Application work normally i show my frame but i cant saw background image on scene.Maybe css not working how i can resolve this problem?

Sory for my bad english thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have numerous problems with your program.

1. You define a style class `mainClass-scene` but never use it.
2. You use the css `-fx-background-image` attribute which only works on [Regions](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html), but you don't have any regions.
3. You apply a drop shadow effect, but don't leave any insets around the background image for the drop shadow to be seen.
4. You set the stage size to the same value as the scene size, but the stage has decorations, on it like title bars, etc so it can't be the same size.
5. It is usually best to retrieve css files as a class resource.

[image: poison]

Here is an updated version which works for me and generates the image above.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainClass extends Application{
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
    stage.setTitle("Hi");

    StackPane layout = new StackPane();
    layout.getStylesheets().add("mainClass.css");
    layout.getStyleClass().add("main-class");

    Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 600, 250);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(
      getClass().getResource("mainClass.css").toExternalForm()
    );
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.centerOnScreen();
    stage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Associated css:

```
/**
 * file: mainClass.css
 *   Place in same directory as MainClass.java.
 *   Have your build system copy this file to your build output directory.
 **/

.main-class {
  -fx-background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mirella-gabriele/fantasy-mediaeval/256/Poison-blue-icon.png');
  -fx-background-repeat: stretch;   
  -fx-background-size: 570 220;
  -fx-background-position: center center;
  -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, black, 30, 0.5, 0, 0); 
  -fx-background-insets: 30;
}
```

Comment: oow awesome work great but i have new problem :( when i add button in stackpane, i want to use specific cordinates; for example: setLayoutX(100) . not working

Comment: StackPane is a [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm), which means it manages the layout values of it's children, so you don't explicitly set those values.  If you want to explicitly set layout values and use css on the parent component, use a [Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) instead of a `StackPane`.  Also try out [SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html) - it will help you understand layouts much better.  Please ask new questions in new questions.